"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." Django REST framework that uses adfs authentication backend
I am working on a django project which uses django_auth_adfs (Azure Active Directory) as its authentication backend. I have set up its API service using rest_framework. In the browsable views of the rest_framework, I am able to authorize using the session authentication which requires my settings.py to have such a thing:
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'django_auth_adfs.rest_framework.AdfsAccessTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}

With this, I am able to send post requests which requires the user to be authorized. But as soon as I change it to (deleting session authentication):
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'django_auth_adfs.rest_framework.AdfsAccessTokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}

I get the http 401 unauthorized error which means it is not able to authorize using the token. This, further causes me not being able to send requests with postman. Does anyone know how I can use the API using adfs tokens?
Here is an overall look of how my settings.py look:
"""
Django settings for core project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my_domain']

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django_auth_adfs.backend.AdfsAuthCodeBackend',
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",

    # Installed apps
    'django_auth_adfs',
    'bench',
    'api',
    'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",

    # Other Middlewares
    'django_auth_adfs.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "core.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'static/templates',
        ],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "core.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "GB"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

STATIC_ROOT = '/usr/share/nginx/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

LOGIN_URL = 'django_auth_adfs:login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'django_auth_adfs:logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'https://my_domain/oauth2/callback'


# Client secret is not public information. Should store it as an environment variable.

client_id = os.getenv('client_id')
client_secret = os.getenv('client_secret')
tenant_id = os.getenv('tenant_id')
email_host_user = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
email_host_password = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')


AUTH_ADFS = {
    'AUDIENCE': client_id,
    'CLIENT_ID': client_id,
    'CLIENT_SECRET': client_secret,
    'CLAIM_MAPPING': {'first_name': 'given_name',
                      'last_name': 'family_name',
                      'email': 'upn'
                      },
    'GROUPS_CLAIM': 'roles',
    'MIRROR_GROUPS': True,
    'USERNAME_CLAIM': 'email',
    'TENANT_ID': tenant_id,
    'RELYING_PARTY_ID': client_id,
}


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = email_host_user

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'django_auth_adfs.rest_framework.AdfsAccessTokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}

This is what I get:

Also, can it be because of the Nginx settings not passing the header as a reverse proxy??
I expected django rest_framework to handle the tokenization itself, but it seems like there is something misconfigured. I tried deactivating the authorization on my api urls and I was able to send get requests and receive the correct response. But I cannot send post requests and also that is not what I want. I want only the people from my azure app (already configured with django_auth_adfs) to send requests.

The problem was with my AUDIENCE in AUTH_ADFS configuration in settings.py.
It should look like this:
AUTH_ADFS = {
    'AUDIENCE': [f'api://{client_id}', client_id],
    'CLIENT_ID': client_id,
    'CLIENT_SECRET': client_secret,
    'CLAIM_MAPPING': {'first_name': 'given_name',
                      'last_name': 'family_name',
                      'email': 'upn'
                      },
    'GROUPS_CLAIM': 'roles',
    'MIRROR_GROUPS': True,
    'USERNAME_CLAIM': 'email',
    'TENANT_ID': tenant_id,
    'RELYING_PARTY_ID': client_id,
    'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS': [
        '^api',  # Assuming you API is available at /api
    ],
}

Meaning I was missing the api://client_id as one of my audiences.
